# Detecting a token with a json object using json.net

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET to de-serialize some JSON from a web service. I'm wanting to detect if a certain token is present and then act on that.

```
JToken token = JObject.Parse(JsonData);
```

I'm using the above to de-serialize the data, i've then tried the following

```
if (((string)token.SelectToken("tokenname")) != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("found");
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

each time it returns not found. Any idea's? thanks

Comment: What does the JSON coming back from the web service look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been doing the following:
(I'm assuming the JsonData is a string)

```
// data is a string variable
JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

if (obj != null) {
    if (obj["someProperty"] != null) {
        // perform logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JObject obj=JObject.Parse(data);

JToken token;

if(obj.TryGetValue("tokenname", out token)) {
Debug.WriteLine(token);
}
```